# Custom url for users profile and product name in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing

I want to create custom urls as follows:

1. When a user creates a profile his username that user will be placed into my domain: `www.mydomain.com/john`
2. When I create a product, the product id is shown in the url: `www.mydomain.com/products/single/1`, and
3. The for the newly created product, the product name is also shown in the url `www.mydomain.com/products/single/New-Dell-Laptop`

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Have you looked at URI Routing http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: i don't understand how to use in my url link

Comment: i am also facing such kind of problem....How to make dynamic custom URL which will be SEO FRIENDLY?